# Can I use an or ( || ) in a where clause?

Tags: swift, generics, types, where-clause

I am trying to extend the `Array` type, but I only want the functions available if the type is `Int` or `Float`.

I know I can do this for one type:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Int { }
```

But can I do it for multiple types? This is sort of what I want:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Int || Iterator.Element == Float { }
```

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This doesn't really work conceptually. Using the where in an extension allows you to use Element as the Type you're specifying. If you're saying it can be multiple Types, you might as well not have the where specifier at all.

If you're looking to add specific functionality for multiple types, I would recommend creating an empty protocol and add adherence to the desired Types. e.g:

```
protocol WorksWithExtension { }

extension Int: WorksWithExtension { }
extension Float: WorksWithExtension { }

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: WorksWithExtension {
    //Do whatever you need to do here
}
```

Comment: I want the users of a library to register their own implementations for a restricted set of interfaces. I want to provide them with a generic "register" method in my library that is constrained to accept only generic types that implement one of a set of allowed protocols. The register function is not calling any of the specific methods, is just working with the types themselves to register them accordingly in the underlying DI system. So... the question still stands

Comment: @RaduSimionescu In that case you would/should be using a Protocol that encapsulates the interface you want your set of protocols to implement, and (optionally) make that interface the parent interface of your set of interfaces. So...the answer still stands ;-)

Comment: of course, I thought of that - it was my first approach actually. BUT, with that approach you are not able to define any kind of contract in that top level Protocol, which makes it useless. The question was whether swift allows "or", not if it is philosophically correct

Comment: Why can't you define a contract? If you want the adhering Types to do something, just add a declaration to say they can do that thing. Otherwise the compiler would have to check the entirety of the Types' interface (including all extension) for common signatures, or just pass the message and potentially crash at run time. The first is impractical, and the second goes against Swift's design philosophy.